# Turn this little R code to JavaScript to scrape that in VSCode

Tags: javascript, r

I start learning JavaScript and want to turn my **R script code** to **JavaScript** and After make a loop to get all available data.
I don't exactly know How to achieve it. I'm using VSCode editor.
For Ticker named **BRVMAG**, data table cand be find in  https://www.sikafinance.com/marches/historiques?s=BRVMAG

```
library(httr2)
library(magrittr)

r <- request("https://www.sikafinance.com/api/general/GetHistos") %>% 
  req_body_json(list('ticker'= 'BRVMAG', 'datedeb'= '2022-02-01', 'datefin'= '2022-03-29','xperiod'= '0')) %>% 
  req_perform() %>%
  resp_body_json(simplifyVector = T)
```

Below is what i done with javascript after inspecting their site

```
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          "accept": "*/*",
          "accept-language": "fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
          "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
          "sec-ch-ua": "\"Chromium\";v=\"104\", \" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"104\"",
          "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?1",
          "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"Android\"",
          "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
          "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
          "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin"
        },
        "referrer": "https://www.sikafinance.com/marches/historiques?s=BRVMAG",
        "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
        "body": "{\"ticker\":\"BRVMAG\",\"datedeb\":\"2022-06-19\",\"datefin\":\"2022-08-16\",\"xperiod\":\"0\"}",
        "method": "POST",
        "mode": "no-cors",
        "credentials": "include"
      };
      
      fetch('https://www.sikafinance.com/api/general/GetHistos', options)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(response => console.log(response))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Please Can someone help me?
If possible create a JavaScript function that Can help me change parameters such as : **Ticker, datedeb, datefin** and **xperiod** and get the data?
[image: Data type is XHR]

Comment: You're more likely to get a response if you show javascript code that you've attempted, and what is not working about it. Not showing the new code can be inferred as "translate this for me" instead of helping you learn javascript.

Comment: Ok thanks. Let me add JavaScript code that i've attempted.

Comment: i added my javascript's code